# How to make your site visible on google search

Tags: google-search, meta-tags

My site has been online for more than 2 months now http://thedatastrategy.com/, I also have set up the default meta data from W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp,

But when I do searches on google for example, "data strategy", "the data strategy", "thedatastrategy" I don't see my site.

But if I do "site:thedatastrategy.com" my site pops up. Thus the domain name is well indexed in the google database.

What more am I supposed to add? Are there some more meta data information I have to add? Or am I supposed to register my site on some google service ?

I am not sure what to do now. When I tried searching this answer on google, I get the response that wait for some time and google would have crawled and indexed your site. But I have already waiting more than 2 months, and the results are like before.

Comment: 1) Your Meta Description needs better content. 2) Your links from Facebook/LinkedIn include www and your website doesn't; pick one version and make that canonical. 3) Link back from your Twitter page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see your website when you search for "data strategy", "the data strategy", "thedatastrategy" that's because there are other websites with stronger domain authority who are targeting these keywords. You have to do proper SEO for your website using these keywords to show your website on first page when someone types these keywords.If you do "site:thedatastrategy.com" and your site shows up that means your website is indexed on google but that doesn't mean it will show your website on the first page for the above mentioned keywords. 
There are two things which you should do when doing basic SEO of your website. 1. Link Building 2. Keyword Research Do a bit of research on these two topics you will find tons of guides and tutorials.

Comment: I am confused when it comes to doing "proper SEO", could you point me to some material which would explain to me in more detail ?

Comment: There are two things which you should do when doing basic SEO of your website.
1. Link Building 
2. Keyword Research 

Do a bit of research on these two topics you will find tons of guides and tutorials

Comment: thank you for the response. Could you add the last comment on the answer? I think it will be helpful to people who might come across this question

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the Google Webmaster Tools ? https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home

Submit your website then you will have better overview/control on the seo.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have gone through your website and noticed it's single page website. What I will suggest you to add more pages on your website as with single page website you can't target many keywords. Google also prefer those sites in search results which have multiple pages with good amount of content. Also the keywords you are trying to rank  "data strategy", "the data strategy", "thedatastrategy" they are quiet competitive keywords and you need to invest in SEO to rank for those keywords. Currently your website have many on-page issues like

1. meta tags are not optimized
2. Header tags are not optimized Your
3. website is working with www and without www

Fix these on-page issues and the start off-page work to rank for those keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very competitive keyword so it'll take some time, providing you get it right. On top of the notes everyone else has suggested, I think you need to get a robots.txt file generated to ensure search engines know that they're allowed to crawl your website. Then get an XML sitemap of your pages generated and submitted to Google Webmaster Tools. Installing Google Analytics won't do any harm either!